# who gave the titles to chopin's etudes op.10?

Tags: piano, performing, history

**Chopin's etudes op. 10 are all named related to some features and shapes of the compositions.**

Who gave these names - that may also say something about their performing - to the études?

**Was it Chopin himself or someone else?**

Comment: this question is quite different, as the other is asking about the WHY? of on specific etude of another opus ...

Comment: but if you read the answers at the other, you will see the answer to your question

Comment: 1. When I posted the question I knew the answer. 2. The search machine couldn't find the connection to op. 25 as I was looking for op. 10. and when I was checking the duplicate I overlooked that the answer was saying in plural: 6

Chopin did not personally give the etude(s) these name(s), as in German the plural is not build by s and the s is like in English a genitiv s. Sorry.
O.K.  I will change the question about nick names and their relation to the composition. ;) later ...
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nicknames are all inauthentic. They were invented by different people at different times, and not all of them are even "standardized" everywhere. For instance, the only name (except for the obvious technical terms like "thirds") that is well-known in my language is "revolutionary".

Answer (score 0):

**Chopin's Études:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tudes_(Chopin)

*Some are so popular they have been given nicknames; arguably the most popular of all is Op. 10, No. 3, sometimes identified by the names "Tristesse" ("Sadness") or "Farewell" ("L'Adieu"), as well as the "Revolutionary Étude" (Op. 10, No. 12).*

No nicknames are of Chopin's original creation!

Opus number and nickname

Étude Op. 10, No. 1 Waterfall

Étude Op. 10, No. 2 Chromatique

Étude Op. 10, No. 3 Tristesse

Étude Op. 10, No. 4 Torrent

Étude Op. 10, No. 5 Black Keys

Étude Op. 10, No. 6 Lament

Étude Op. 10, No. 7 Toccata

Étude Op. 10, No. 8 Sunshine

Étude Op. 10, No. 9

Étude Op. 10, No. 10

Étude Op. 10, No. 11 Arpeggio

Étude Op. 10, No. 12 Revolutionary